# Eclipse PHP debugging only works on first page (doesn't follow links)

Tags: php, debugging

I am having trouble getting PHP web debugging setup in Eclipse. I am able to step through the code on the main page `http://localhost/app/index.php`.

But as soon as I navigate to another page within this same app (being routed through `index.php`) the debug in Eclipse no longer picks up any of the routing (just shows as `<terminated, exit value: 0>http://localhost/app/index.php`).

In the past (6-8 months ago), I had this working with the same versions of Eclipse, PHP, XAMPP, Zend debugger, etc. I even made notes on how everything was setup, but for the life of me I cannot get it work again.

I do notice that the `debug_host, start_debug, debug_port` and other debug related URL params go away as soon as I navigate away from the original page. In some cases, I can copy and paste them onto the end of the new URL and it will send that page through the debugger, but this time none of the Ajax calls hit the debugger.

I have Googled to my heart's content with no luck, so any insight into what I may be doing wrong is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to follow up on this in case someone comes across it via a search.

I'm not sure of the actual reason that the **Debug all pages** option doesn't work, but by selecting **Start Debug from**, entering the URL to my index page, and then checking **Continue Debug from This Page** seemed to solve my problem.